# Laravel device authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm struggling with the implementation of device authentication in Laravel auth, so thing is that I want to restrict users to login into a maximum of 5 devices only, but the catch is that in a single device he can log in with as many browsers as he wants.

I have tried to use `exec('getmac')`, but this works on my local machine only not on the Linux server. We can't use ip address as it's not unique and also dynamic usually.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe you would use this

```
shell_exec('getmac');
```

**or**

[system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) — Execute an external program and display the output

[shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

hopefully that is help you

Comment: Thank you @Ossama Abd but these function only works in localhost, after deploying in Linux they are not working...